# Select max value from column, except have specific value in other column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table, describing some plants

```
p_id   p_type  p_name      p_size  p_tasty
   1   veggie  potato           1        0
   2   veggie  carrot           2        0
   3   veggie  cabbage          3        0
   4   fruit   strawberry       1        1
   5   fruit   apple            2        0
   6   fruit   watermelon       3        0
```

if i want to get the largest plant of every type, the query will be like this:

```
SELECT a.p_id,a.p_type, a.p_name,a.p_size,a.p_tasty
FROM test.plants a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT b.p_type, MAX(b.p_size) p_size
    FROM test.plants b
    GROUP BY b.p_type
) b ON a.p_type = b.p_type AND a.p_size = b.p_size
```

and will give me this:

```
p_id    p_type  p_name      p_size  p_tasty
3       veggie  cabbage     3       0
6       fruit   watermelon  3       0
```

But how can i get the largest OR the tastiest plant of every type?

***i.e.,*** select plant that has p_tasty value of 1, and if there is no such plant of this type, select the largest one.

I think i could use `case when exists then ...` clause, but maybe there is simpler way to do this?

Comment: Consider showing the records row by row, instead of showing as a bunch. That's more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` your query with the tasty plants, and use the largest as a default if there's no tasty plant.

```
SELECT IFNULL(c.p_id, a.p_id) AS p_id, a.p_type, IFNULL(c.p_name, a.p_name) AS p_name, IFNULL(c.p_size, a.p_size) AS p_size, IFNULL(c.p_tasty, a.p_tasty) AS p_tasty
FROM test.plants a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT b.p_type, MAX(b.p_size) p_size
    FROM test.plants b
    GROUP BY b.p_type
) b ON a.p_type = b.p_type AND a.p_size = b.p_size
LEFT JOIN test.plants c ON a.p_type = c.p_type AND c.tasty = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

alternatively use partition by on the row_number() order by the columns as you want:

```
    ; with cte as
(
select  a.p_id,
        a.p_type, 
        a.p_name, 
        a.p_size,
        a.p_tasty, 
        ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by a.p_type order by a.p_tasty DESC, a.p_size DESC) as rn
    FROM plants a
)
select cte.p_id, cte.p_type, cte.p_name, cte.p_size, cte.p_tasty
 from cte
 where rn = 1
```